Backing up single-node ClickHouse data with restic to S3
What are the pros/cons of using restic to backup a single-node ClickHouse to S3 vs using built-in functionality and/or clickhouse-backup script from Altinity?
My main concern is if restic can handle backups while clickhouse-server is running, but maybe there are other things that I'm missing?
The reason I'm considering restic setup is because of simplicity of setting up restic. My main concerns of other setups are:

built-in ClickHouse backups to S3 require more effort to support incremental backups (e.g. keeping local state of the previous "base" backup metadata)
Altinity's clickhouse-backup setup for incremental backups requires last backup to be available locally so it can calculate diff.


restic itself know nothing about clickhouse, and possible situation when it try to backup flush-in-progress files
you could use kopia
look details in https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-backup/tree/master/test/integration/kopia/
and https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-backup/blob/master/test/integration/config-custom-kopia.yml
